# Excel pivot table: How to hide zero values

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

I've got two tables and two pivot tables for each of them respectively. In the first table, the duration of each task is calculated on a column called "duration", but in the second one, there is no such column and duration of each task is a calculated field in the pivot table. As you can see, in the first pivot table, tasks with zero time are not shown. But in the second pivot table, where durations are calculated fields, zero time tasks are shown as "0:00". How can I hide zero times like in the first table?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your PivotTable and select Pivot-Table Options, then use the `For empty cells, show` option - like here:

[image]

Ok, in case there is a Number like 0 or 00:00 in your Data and you don't want to display this too, you can solve it with a custom number format - like `#` or `hh:mm:ss;hh:mm:ss;"";`.

In excel's help you find this: `<POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<NULL>;<TEXT>` as the basic form for user-formats - so, this format here `[h]:mm;[h]:mm;"";@` hides `00:00`.

Comment: It's already checked but it does not seem to do the trick. I guess the problem is that those cells are not empty and therefore are shown! (even though their value is 0:00)

Comment: Ok, this was not obvious from your example. Then you can solve this with a custom Number-Format - for usual Numbers i.e. with # as number format. Just a sec, i'll look how to do it for time.

Comment: @Meysam - try my format, worked fine on my example.

Comment: I am currently using this custom number format: `[h]:mm;@`. But still am seeing 0:00 values. Are you suggesting I use another format? Please note that I have chosen this format so that I can correctly see the hour values exceeding 24 http://stackoverflow.com/q/12834115/69537

Comment: well, my suggestion based on setting up the format for the zero-case - you find this in excel help as `<POSITIVE>;<NEGATIVE>;<NULL>;<TEXT>` - when you use only two parts, like you did, then it is interpreted as `<POSITIVE&NULL>;<NEGATIVE>` - try this maybe, can't hurt to try: `[h]:mm;[h]:mm;"";@`

Comment: Well, it worked! Thank you. Please update your answer with this format.

Comment: This worked too: `[h]:mm;[h]:mm;`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Calculated field 
in the formula box type : =IF(Value=0, "NA",Value)
Now when there is a zero value it will force an error

Right click on your PivotTable and select Pivot-Table Options, then check the For error values, show option is ticked and blank

The added benefit of this method is the 0 value is not included in any totals or averages and the points will not print on any of the pivot charts

Answer (score -1):

You can use conditional formatting for whole sheet or pivot area.
Set new rule. "Format only cells that contain" and set "equal to 0" and set text color to white.
Actualy it hides 0 but works.